# llamar formularios desde una sql

Tags: c#

estoy haciendo un proyecto en C# y tengo una tabla en SQL que arma un menú dinámico árbol y uno de los campos tiene el nombre del formulario que debe abrir al hacer click.

Ahora para no hacer una consulta fija y perder el efecto de dinámico del armado del menú, quiero usar una llamada que pueda ser única y que le asigne el nombre del formulario que necesito y lo instancie y llame.

Por ejemplo

En el menú, cuando elijo facturación, llama al formulario `frmFacturacion`

Yo deberia escribir

```
frmFacturacion fact = new frmFacturacion();
fact.Show();
```

Ahora el `frmFacturacion` debe ser variable según cada opción de menú elija.

Espero me entiendan y haya una posibilidad de hacerlo.

Gracias

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Si son del tipo Form podrías usar `Activator.CreateInstance` 
Sabiendo cual es el namespace, reemplaza el string por el "namespace" del mismo o pásalo por parámetro si así lo deseas (si tienes distintos namespaces lo almacenas en la db y haces lo mismo que el form).

```
  string strNombreForm = "frmFacturacion";
  var formObj = Activator.CreateInstance(Type.GetType("namespace." + formtocall)) as Form;
  formObj .ShowDialog();
```

Comment: luciano: el "frmFacturacion" que vos mencionas es una variable que recibe cada nombre del campo de la tabla ??

Comment: Claro es el nombre de la tabla que llega de la DB, eso lo reemplazas con tu código dinamico.

Comment: Excelente Luciano, muchas gracias por la ayuda. Esta tarde lo pruebo y te digo. Abrazos

Comment: Luciano: muchas gracias por la ayuda. funcionó perfecto

Comment: Perfecto Pablo, si esta es la respuesta a la pregunta marcarla como tal así ya queda asentada. Saludos!